# How to add custom method in laravel library

Tags: php, laravel, cloudinary, versionupgrade

How to add custom method in laravel library which is not removed when laravel version update or PHP version update, I am using Cloudinary library "https://github.com/jrm2k6/cloudder" , I need to add a custom function which is not included in the library.

```
 public function uploadLargeVideo($source, $publicId = null, $uploadOptions = array(), $tags = array())
{
    $options = array_merge($uploadOptions, ['resource_type' => 'video']);
    return $this->upload_large($source, $publicId,  $options, $tags);
}
```

Comment: You could define your own version of the library by simply creating a class that extends the library. You can than overwrite/add functions, while still calling the parent functions of needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class extending the class provided by the library.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Support;

use JD\Cloudder\Facades\Cloudder as BaseCloudder;

class Cloudder extends BaseCloudder
{
    // add your methods here
}
```

then use `App\Support\Cloudder` instead of `JD\Cloudder\Facades\Cloudder` in your controller.